# Elasticsearch: How can I use dynamic templates, index objects with date ranges, and search with date-range queries?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, date-range

The following sequence of HTTP requests sent from Postman to an Elasticsearch 7.17.5 server yields two search hits corresponding to objects with dates 2022-07-27T00:00:00.000Z and 2022-07-28T23:59:59.999Z.

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/commit
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "date": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "uuuu-MM-dd[['T'][ ]HH:mm[:ss[.[SSS][SS][S]][,[SSS][SS][S]]]][XXXXX][XXXX][X]"
            }
        }
    }
}

PUT http://localhost:9200/commit/_doc/commit20220727?refresh
{
    "date": "2022-07-27T00:00:00.000Z"
}

PUT http://localhost:9200/commit/_doc/commit20220728?refresh
{
    "date": "2022-07-28T00:00:00.000Z"
}

POST http://localhost:9200/commit/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "range" : {
            "date" : { 
                "gte": "2022-07-27T00:00:00.000Z",
                "lte": "9999-12-31T23:59:59.999Z"
            }
        }
    }
}

DELETE http://localhost:9200/commit
```

Similarly, the following sequence of HTTP requests yields two search hits corresponding to objects with date ranges [2022-07-27T00:00:00.000Z TO 2022-07-27T23:59:59.999Z] and [2022-07-28T00:00:00.000Z TO 2022-07-28T23:59:59.999Z].

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/commit
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "dateTimeRange": {
                "type": "date_range",
                "format": "uuuu-MM-dd[['T'][ ]HH:mm[:ss[.[SSS][SS][S]][,[SSS][SS][S]]]][XXXXX][XXXX][X]"
            }
        }
    }
}

PUT http://localhost:9200/commit/_doc/commit20220727?refresh
{
    "dateTimeRange": {
        "gte": "2022-07-27T00:00:00.000Z", 
        "lte": "2022-07-27T23:59:59.999Z"
    }
}

PUT http://localhost:9200/commit/_doc/commit20220728?refresh
{
    "dateTimeRange": {
        "gte": "2022-07-28T00:00:00.000Z", 
        "lte": "2022-07-28T23:59:59.999Z"
    }
}

Same search and delete requests
```

Similarly, the following sequence of HTTP requests yields two search hits corresponding to objects with dates 2022-07-27T00:00:00.000Z and 2022-07-28T23:59:59.999Z.

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/commit
{
    "mappings": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
            {
                "date": {
                    "match": "date_*",
                    "match_mapping_type": "string",
                    "mapping": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "uuuu-MM-dd[['T'][ ]HH:mm[:ss[.[SSS][SS][S]][,[SSS][SS][S]]]][XXXXX][XXXX][X]"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

PUT http://localhost:9200/commit/_doc/commit20220727?refresh
{
    "date_/date": "2022-07-27T00:00:00.000Z"
}

PUT http://localhost:9200/commit/_doc/commit20220728?refresh
{
    "date_/date": "2022-07-28T00:00:00.000Z"
}

Same search and delete requests
```

But the following sequence of HTTP requests yields zero search hits.

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/commit
{
    "mappings": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
            {
                "date": {
                    "match": "date_*",
                    "match_mapping_type": "string",
                    "mapping": {
                        "type": "date_range",
                        "format": "uuuu-MM-dd[['T'][ ]HH:mm[:ss[.[SSS][SS][S]][,[SSS][SS][S]]]][XXXXX][XXXX][X]"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

PUT http://localhost:9200/commit/_doc/commit20220727?refresh
{
    "date_/date": {
        "gte": "2022-07-27T00:00:00.000Z", 
        "lte": "2022-07-27T23:59:59.999Z"
    }
}

PUT http://localhost:9200/commit/_doc/commit20220728?refresh
{
    "date_/date": {
        "gte": "2022-07-28T00:00:00.000Z", 
        "lte": "2022-07-28T23:59:59.999Z"
    }
}

Same search and delete requests
```

How can I use dynamic templates, index objects with date ranges, and search with date-range queries?

Answer (score 1):

The date dynamic template's match mapping type must be object, not string.

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/commit
{
    "mappings": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
            {
                "date": {
                    "match": "date_*",
                    "match_mapping_type": "object",
                    "mapping": {
                        "type": "date_range",
                        "format": "uuuu-MM-dd[['T'][ ]HH:mm[:ss[.[SSS][SS][S]][,[SSS][SS][S]]]][XXXXX][XXXX][X]"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```